# Hide text in SharePoint 2013 using script editor

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, css, script-editor-webpart

I am trying to hide the date (see screenshot) because it displays the wrong date.

Probably for now the easiest way to fix is to hide the date.

When I click on the date it brings me to:

```
<span title="11-11-2020 00:11" class="zhga-documentdate">11-01-2020</span>
```

Can somebody help me out with a script to hide the date?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of the below solution:

**Using CSS**:

```
span.zhga-documentdate {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Add this CSS at the end of your custom CSS.

**Using JS**:

```
document.querySelector("span.zhga-documentdate").style.display = "none";
```

Add this code in your existing JS (Somewhere after the `span` element is created in DOM).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. You may need some try and error because SharePoint have its existing JS.

```
<script language='Javascript'>
document.getElementsByClassName('zhga-documentdate')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to do the trick:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .zhga-documentdate {display:none !important;}
</style>
```